# API for UAN details displaying from EPFO site

Tags: android, api

IHi i am creating an Android application which is used show the UAN details . I already googled it. But i am not able to find any solution for this.

I am searching for some API that i can get UAN details from EPFO site. Can anyone know any API that providing the same ?

Comment: How can you expect public APIs for a confidential government database?

Comment: public api in the sense we can pass the UAN login details.after the validation we can.. right ?